# How do I compare 1000 items every minute over 1 million records in mongodb without pulling all the data?

Tags: performance, mongodb, optimization, nosql, query-performance

I am developing a real time stock price alert system that gets new prices every 1 min. There are 1000 tradable assets from one exchange currently and I plan to add other exchanges soon and 1 million records are stored in the database currently. A user is able to add alerts on any of the assets and is to be notified in real time (every minute)

The user would add alerts of type **"Alert me if XYZ reaches 100$"** I am using redis to store the current prices and mongodb to store the alerts.If the current price of the asset is 90$, this alert is considered to be a **"greater than"** alert else it is a **"less than"** alert. This attribute is represented by direction in the database. Here's what a single alert in the database looks like...

```
{
    "_id" : //alert id,
    "2" : //user id,
    "3" : e1:XYZ:1, //exchange: asset: direction
    "4" : 100,
    "5" : 0
}
```

I am indexing this database over the field "3". After 1 min, when I fetch all the stock prices, I want to be able to find all the **"greater than"** alerts that are below the current price indicating that the price has risen and all the "lesser" alerts that are above the current price indicating that the price has fallen.

**Approach 1**

I dynamically build a query in mongodb that is of the form

```
db.getCollections("alerts").find({
$or: [
{3: "e1:XYZ:0", 4: {$gt: 100}},
{3: "e1:XYZ:1", 4: {$lt: 100}},
...2000 more assets here
]
})
```

The process above is limited by the 16 MB document size restriction applicable while querying Mongodb

**Approach 2**

I found the above approach was very slow and therefore decided to get all the alerts stored in the database and do the comparisons on my node.js server which takes rougly 2.5 seconds per round to fetch data currently

- Right way to do 1000 comparisons like this (server side or mongodb side)?
- Can I further reduce the amount of data being sent from the database
  to server in any way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you add "_id" to your index `{"3":1, "_id":1 }` and then [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) of `{"_id":1, "3":1}` to query, you get result directly from index in the memory (if you have enough memory to hold index in the memory).

Adition, you could use [in-memory](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/inmemory/) database engine.

Comment: thanks for the pointer, since i am using redis already, i believe it complements the in memory database concepts, the 1000 assets need to be queried over 160 fiat currencies resulting in a potential 250k queries, i dont think sending that many conditions to the database would be a good idea, only thing i can think of is querying the entire database of alerts every minute, should i store all the alert values as a nested collection under each asset, there is a 16MB limit if i am not mistaken, any pointers/strategies will be super helpful, thanks